# Scraping data > stop at white line

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, row

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import json
import os

jaren = [str("2012"), str("2010"), str("2006"), str("2003"),str("2002"), str("1998"), str("1994"), str("1989"), str("1986"), str("1982"), str("1981"), str("1977"), str("1972"), str("1971"), str("1967"), str("1963"), str("1959"), str("1956")]
DESIRED_COLUMNS = {1, 2, 5} #scrapes only afk, aantal & zetels
verkiezingsData = []

filename = raw_input('Enter a filename: ') or 'data.json'

#open file and open json array
with open(filename, "w") as file:
   file.write("[{")
for Jaargetal in jaren:

     #url source 
     r = urllib.urlopen("http://www.nlverkiezingen.com/TK" + Jaargetal +".html").read()
     soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
     tables = soup.find_all("table")
     for table in tables:
         header = soup.find_all("h1")[0].getText()

         #print header
         with open(filename, "a+") as file:
              file.write("\"%s\": [" % header) #header as beginning json
         trs = table.find_all("tr")[0].getText()
         del verkiezingsData[:] #clear list before adding new data


         #add the 3 columns to a list
         for tr in table.find_all("tr")[:22]: #22 aantal columns van top till bottom
             for index, val in enumerate(tr.find_all('td')):
                  if index in DESIRED_COLUMNS: #linkt naar desired columns bovenin
                      verkiezingsData.append(val.getText().strip())


         #json array van de 3 vallues
         for a, b, c in zip(verkiezingsData[::3],        verkiezingsData[1::3], verkiezingsData[2::3]): #link naar desired columns 1,2,5
             data2 = {'afk':a,"aantal":b, "zetels":c}

             #file writing
             with open(filename, 'a') as outfile:
                 json.dump(data2, outfile)
                    outfile.write(",")


        #open file, delete last comma and close array
        with open(filename, 'ab+') as file:
                file.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
                file.truncate()
                file.write("],")

#open file, delete last comma, and close array
with open(filename, 'r+b') as file:
    file.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    file.truncate()
    file.write("}]")

#open file and pretty print json data
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    prettydata = json.load(file)
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    json.dump(prettydata, file, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

I made a scraper which scrapes from nlverkiezingen.com

When it saves as a json file:

```
"Tweede-Kamerverkiezingen - 12 september 2012": [
            {
                "aantal": "Aantal",
                "afk": "Afk.",
                "zetels": "Zetels"
            },
            {
                "aantal": "2504948",
                "afk": "VVD",
                "zetels": "41"
            },
```

The first row is: Aantal/Afk/Zetels.
I don't want this to be scraped.

**How can I change this? That the scraping begins from the second row**

The second thing is, that the last row is everywhere different. sometimes the 20th row, 15th row.

**How can I change this? That the scraping ends when he sees a white/empty row when it is scraping?**

Answer (score 0):

do not know if get it right, it is just a guess, but maybe something like

```
for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:22]
```

to skip the first row?

Answer (score 0):

> The first row is: Aantal/Afk/Zetels. I don't want this to be scraped.

Replace
`for tr in table.find_all("tr")[:22]:` with
`for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:22]:`

Python has zero-based indexing, so `1` refers to the second row in your table.

> How can I change this? That the scraping ends when he sees a white/empty row when it is scraping?

The `&nbsp;` in the empty table cells will be parsed by BeautifulSoup as the `u"\xa0"` Python string. Check the content of the first  tag on each row and compare it to that value, and use that for breaking out of your loop.

Comment: I don't get what I need to do at with the &nbsp; could you maybe tell me what kind of code i need to edit in? @sahuk where can I say to each "year/website" it need to quit at a certain row? Now I can only quit it at 1:22